# Laravel: fields not inserting

Tags: php, laravel

I have four fields that are not being inserted into my products table, I have checked that those fields have values but they are not being inserted and these fields are populated by a select box except for the `created_by` field.

Products Table Schema:

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('supplier_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('brand_id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('slug'); 
    etc....
});
```

Saving the product:

```
$product = Product::create([
    'created_by'     => Auth::user()->id,
    'supplier_id'    => intval($request['supplier_id']),
    'category_id'    => $request['category_id'],
    'brand_id'       => $request->get('brand_id'),
    'title'          => $request->get('title'),
    'slug'           => str_slug( $request->get('title'), '-' ),
    etc...
)};
```

All the fields hold values when submitted but the fields (`supplier_id`, `category_id`, `brand_id`, `created_by`) are not being inserted into the table - they have values which are strings

My Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = "products";

    protected $fillable = [
        'supplier_id', 'category_id', 'brand_id', 'title', 'slug',
        'created_by', 'updated_by'
    ];
}


use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTableProducts extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        // Create table for storing products
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('supplier_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('brand_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('slug');            
            $table->string('keywords', 160);
            $table->integer('template_id')->unsigned();            
            $table->text('video_clip')->nullable();
            $table->text('body')->nullable();            
            $table->boolean('active');
            $table->boolean('clearance');
            $table->string('sku', 100);
            $table->string('quantity');
            $table->decimal('unit_price');    
            $table->decimal('sell_price');
            $table->decimal('sale_discount')->nullable();
            $table->datetime('sale_start')->nullable();
            $table->datetime('sale_end')->nullable();
            $table->string('promo_code', 20)->nullable();
            $table->double('promo_discount')->nullable();            
            $table->datetime('promo_start')->nullable();
            $table->datetime('promo_end')->nullable();
            $table->decimal('default_freight');
            $table->decimal('international_freight')->nullable();
            $table->decimal('expedited_freight')->nullable();
            $table->string('weight');
            $table->string('dimensions');
            $table->text('measurements')->nullable();
            $table->integer('created_by')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('updated_by')->unsigned()->nullable();            
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->unique(array('title','slug'));
        });

        Schema::table('products', function(Blueprint $table) {            
            $table->foreign('created_by')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('updated_by')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('supplier_id')->references('id')->on('suppliers');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
            $table->foreign('brand_id')->references('id')->on('brands');
            $table->foreign('template_id')->references('id')->on('templates');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('products');
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check your form ? only four filed then what about other fields ?

Comment: Those four fields won't insert but everything else inserts

Comment: Please create a new variable (i.e. $data) and assign it the array you're passing to Product::create(). Then do `var_dump($data)` and make sure all the needed fields are filled.

Comment: in your save method check check `$input = $request->all();` `dd($input);` weather you will get input from your form ??

Comment: I get the input from my form if you check my update that's what comes out of my var_dump

Comment: Ok so I went into phpmyadmin and manually changed the category_id field to 1 for a record and it won't put the value in so it's something to do with my database any ideas why this is happening

Comment: @ONYX `'supplier_id' => string '1' (length=1)` is string is that correct ?? because in integer column we can't insert string right ?

Comment: It's not the fact that it's a string, phpmyadmin won't let me just add the category_id manually and says 0 rows affected on an update

Comment: I've updated my code to show my full schema for products table

Comment: in your Model take of `protected $fillable`  only use `protected $guarded = [];`

Comment: if not problem with your controller function how you get foreign keys i guess

Comment: I haven't solved this problem aye lol

Comment: It's the table relationship that's the problem, when there is no relationship the fields insert, so it's something to do with the database table products cos when I manually add an ID value to any of those fields the field doesn't get updated through phpmyadmin

Comment: Do the corresponding foreign keys exist?

Comment: Hey I know that this is an 4 year old issue but I'm struggling with that right now...
@ONYX did you found the solution, bcs same problem here with string values...

Comment: as for me it was just a . instead of , in `protected $fillable = [ ..., 'start_from'. 'end_to', ]`

Answer (score -3):

In the "Saving the product" bit, to actually save the product you must call:
$product->save();

Edit- Indeed you don't need to. Not sure if i should delete this or leave it here.

Comment: When using `Model::create([])` you don't need to call `save()`

Comment: Right, my bad. Then are you getting some kind of error? There should be one if it doesn't get inserted.

Comment: an error isn't always thrown, he successfully inserts the row to the table, he is just missing fields.